# CSS Accordion Nav - Need default tree open IF no others are open

Tags: html, css, navigation

I made a navigation bar essentially using this guide:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/verticalaccordionav/

What I need is for one default tree (header + sub-links) to be expanded upon page load, which I know I can do by declaring the height to that section in the CSS. The problem is, I only want it to stay expanded IF no other trees are expanded i.e. no other categories are hovered over. Basically: only 1 tree should be expanded at a time, but I'd like when no trees are being hovered over for the default to be the expanded tree.

Any way to do this? CSS-only solution is preferred, but I have a feeling this requires if/then statements and thus can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have done it with out much thought using jq, but since you want it a css solution you got it :), it has a caveat, your user must have the mouse over any part of your website, but as soon as he goes lets say to the browser toolbar or to check another tab it will hide back, but usually when the user is doing that is either about to leave your site or not focused on whats going on on it.

[**Here is the Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8FRr/)

You must add this css rules:

```
alpha {
   height: 38px;
   overflow: hidden;
    /*Animation*/
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
       -o-transition: height 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
          transition: height 1s ease;
}

html:hover .alpha, .menu-item.alpha:hover {
   height:130px;
}
nav:hover .alpha{
    height: 38px;
}
```

Css approaches usually are harder to think but they come with nice advantages, good luck with you project.

Comment: You are awesome Zarich, thanks a bunch! This is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: You welcome, i'm glad it helped =), next time add a jsfiddle with your question and you'll get faster answers ;)